# Long haul flight density at Dulles International Airport

Tags: data-request, medical, global, travel

I have an emergency department admission data-set for deep vein thrombosis. Long haul travel is a risk factor for DVT. I would like data on long haul travel to see if there is any correlation with DVT. Therefore I would like information on the number of long haul flights at Dulles International Airport over the course of the year. For example are there peak months?